# Parse.com file download with another name

Tags: html, file, parse-platform, download

So, actually I have different type of files (pdf, docx,etc) in my Parse Javascript app. The problem is that when I download a file using the url() method I get the entire name "tfss-ad38e137...-filename.pdf" but I want to download the file just as "filename.pdf". I have already tried using the download attribute on the `<a>` element with no solution.

So, I dynamically add this code:

```
query3.find({
  success: function(results) {
    console.log("ID CARPETA: " + idCarpeta);
    //Si los resultados son mayores a 0 entonces aplicamos el height al div
    if( results.length > 0)
      {
          setTimeout(function(){
              $('#' + idCarpeta).height(130);
              }, 300);
      }

    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var object = results[i];

        var archivo = object.get('archivo');
        var nombre= archivo.name();
        console.log("Name: " + nombre);
        var nameParts = nombre.split("-");
        var filename = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];

        //ahora encontramos el tipo de archivo
        var filenameParts = filename.split(".");
        var tipo = filenameParts[1];

        console.log("Tipo de file: " + tipo);


        if(tipo == "pdf")
        {
            codigo = '<div id="tipo ' + contador + '" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 box2 clearfix tipo' + contador + '">' + 
                        '<div class="box3">' + 
                            '<p><i class="icono-archivo fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></p>' + 
                            '<p><b>' + filename + '</b></p>' + 
                        '</div>' + 
                        '<div class="mask mask' + contador + '"><a download="' + filename + '" href="' + archivo.url() + '" ><span class="fa fa-download fa-3x"></span><span class="descargar">Descargar</span></div></a>' + 
                    '</div>';
        }
        if(tipo == "jpeg" || tipo == "jpg")
        {
            codigo = '<div id="tipo ' + contador + '" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 box2 clearfix tipo' + contador + '">' + 
                        '<div class="box3">' + 
                            '<p><i class="icono-archivo fa fa-file-image-o"></i></p>' + 
                            '<p><b>' + filename + '</b></p>' + 
                        '</div>' + 
                        '<div class="mask mask' + contador + '"><a download="' + filename + '" href="' + archivo.url() + '" ><span class="fa fa-download fa-3x"></span><span class="descargar">Descargar</span></div></a>' + 
                    '</div>';

  ...
}
```

As you can see I have the file name in the filename variable and try to use this in the "download" attribute but with no success. Please if somebody knows I would really appreciate it, is really ugly to download files with that large name.

Comment: Please include code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: I added the code, do you have any clues jeffdill2?